# Wrong partial is rendered in Rails in some cases, possible fragment caching issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-5.1, fragment-caching

I have a template that displays a list of events

```
<tbody>
<%= render partial: 'event', collection: events, cached: true %>
</tbody>
```

The partial `event`:

```
<% cache event do %>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Something
    </td>
    <td>
      <%= render 'identifiable_link_with_tag', identifiable: event.identifiable %>
    </td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

The partial `identifiable_link_with_tag`:

```
<% cache identifiable do %>
    <span class="badge badge-info"><%= identifiable.type %></span> <%= link_to identifiable.identifier, identifiable %>
<% end %>
```

Now, the odd thing is what follows. Sometimes I notice in the events view that for some events another partial (`identifiable`) is rendered instead of `identifiable_link_with_tag`: `_identifiable`. This seems very odd, and on a page that lists 25 events, this would only happen for 1 or 2 or 3 (or 0) events.

So in short, it seems that sometimes the wrong identifiable is rendered. I do use Rails fragment caching, so that may be a factor. Am I missing something or have I encountered a Rails bug? This issue is very hard to reproduce in development, thus hard to debug.

Comment: Are you getting the wrong `event` partial or `identifiable_link_with_tag`? What exactly is wrong? One thing with Russian doll caching is that update to any `identifiable` will not expire the `event` partial it is nested in unless that event is `touched`. Not sure if that's the problem you're facing.

Comment: @EJ2015 it's not an issue regarding outdated information, I am aware of that. Instead of the partial `identifiable_link_with_tag`, the partial for `identifiable` itself is rendered (see updated answer)

Comment: Are you also caching the partial `identifiable`? Maybe that is using the same cache key as the corresponding `identifiable_link_with_tag`, if you're also doing `cache identifiable` there too? If so you can try using a custom cache key for one of them.

Comment: @EJ2015 Yes I am also caching `identifiable` partial! I was thinking of some kind of cache key collision too, but if so is this a bug in Rails or not?

Comment: The key should include a template digest. So this seems unlikely. But this is the only thing I can think of. Can you test it?

Comment: Please check server logs carefully and try to update the snippet when it renders different partial than the one you mentioned in views. @edwardmp

Comment: Consider adding the content of the `identifiable_link_with_tag` and `identifiable` partials. This will probably help with debugging.